# Why is the "have to" in "must have to" not redundant here?

Tags: redundancy, have-to-versus-must

> We can use **must have to** to say that we conclude something based on what we know about a present situation ...
>
> - I can't access the database. You **must have to put in** a password. (= a password is necessary)
>
> — [*Advanced Grammar in Use with Answers*](https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=NY8oAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA36&dq=%22You+must+have+to+put+in+a+password.%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUrYKLyq3uAhW8zDgGHZzcAbMQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22You%20must%20have%20to%20put%20in%20a%20password.%22) by Martin Hewings

Why can’t one say “You must put in a password” in this context?

Comment: @JRodge01 These sentences were from an advanced English grammar book. One of the users has edited my original message, which should actually read: "- I can’t access the database. - You must have to put in a password. Why can’t one say “You must put in a password.”? The same user has provided a situation where "must have to" would make sense. I just wonder if simple "must" can be used in the answer.

Comment: @Cascabel  Yes, it's a Cambridge book. Thanks all for your input.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the speaker is trying to convey.

Using either "must" or "have to" asserts that the statement is truth.

> You have to put in a password.
>
> You must put in a password.

Those both convey the same idea that there is only one path forward and that the speaker is absolutely certain.

Using both "must" and "have to" in the same sentence creates a strong assumption.

> You must have to put in a password.

This meaans "I'm not certain, but I'm very confidant that you have to put in a password".

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs#Must_and_have_to) explains it as:

> When used with the perfect infinitive (i.e. with have and the past participle), must expresses only assumption [.]To express obligation or necessity in the past, had to or some other synonym must be used.

Comment: @Cascabel, would you accept the following? "I can't get into the database.  I'm sure I used the right username." "Did you enter a password?" "No" "You must be required to put in a password."  And if that's acceptable, would replacing "be required to" with "have to" be acceptable?  In my mind, it's quite natural.

Comment: @Juhasz Spot on.  In the sort of context you mention what is really meant is that ‘it must be the case that’ you have to enter a password.  This is not an obligation.  It’s just that IT must be the case that YOU have to put in a password (or the programme won’t load).